# Outlook to use high-dpi rendering, even over remote desktop, even after logging out and in

Tags: microsoft-outlook, remote-desktop, dpi, high-dpi

I use Windows 10 with some high-dpi screens and a 200% font scaling.  Microsoft Outlook 2016 just about works when run locally; it shows nicely rendered text at the correct size.  (It often starts up with the window unusably small, not even showing the title bar; and it often gets into a state where it stops updating the display and everything goes blank; but these irritations are not the subject of this Q&A.)

Anyway, I also remote desktop into the machine.  This is using a third party remote desktop client which appears to be some mutant of mstsc.exe, and is launched for me without options from a web page, so I can't fiddle DPI settings in the client.  Nonetheless I do get a usable desktop, spanning high-dpi monitors on the client, without any global pixel scaling or blurriness.  Applications on the client display the same as they do on the local desktop -- provided you connect to an existing session.

The problem comes when you log out or reboot and then have to **log on** via remote desktop, starting a new desktop session.  In this case the dpi settings are different and there's no way to change them, since "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session."  Some have suggested workarounds where you right-click on the desktop and get to dpi settings that way, but this didn't work for me.

The new dpi settings you get when logging on via remote desktop are not that bad.  The mouse pointer is still the right size.  Firefox renders everything just as before.  But lots of programs now render at low resolution and get a 2x scaling up applied by Windows.  Two examples are Microsoft Outlook and PuTTy.  They work, but look ugly and pixellated compared to the normal high-dpi smoothness.

For PuTTY I was able to fix the problem by right-clicking on the shortcut.  Under Properties there is a Compatibility tab, which has a Change High DPI Settings button.  I set the first section, "Use this setting..." to "Use the DPI that's set for my main display when: I open this program".  And I set "Scaling performed by: Application".  Now PuTTY renders correctly.

If only I could do the same for Outlook!  But it has no Compatibility tab.  The Properties dialogue box is there, but Compatibility just doesn't appear.  This happens whether viewing properties for the shortcut or directly for outlook.exe.  (Many have wondered why this tab appears for some programs and not others.  Some say that 64-bit applications don't get one, but that can't be the case, since I have a 64-bit build of PuTTY.  It can be a policy setting to stop showing the tab globally, but clearly that's not the case here either.  Does anyone know?)

Anyway, given that I can't get to the Compatibility tab, is there a way to set Outlook to use correct dpi settings?

Answer (score 0):

In the registry under

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

there was an entry for PuTTY with value

```
~ PERPROCESSSYSTEMDPIFORCEON HIGHDPIAWARE
```

I created a new string value whose name is the full path of outlook.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
```

and I gave it the value above.  Now Outlook renders properly.  (I also deleted the shortcut I was using to start Outlook, which was some kind of magic shortcut created by the Office installer, and made a new shortcut directly to the above executable.  I don't know whether this step is needed.)

I had previously tried editing the binary data under `Compatibility Assistant\Store` but that didn't have any effect.